# xss attack on value field by bypassing encoded double quotes

Tags: xss

consider a website that handles search query like this:

```
<input class="something" type="search-field" value="SEARCHQUERY">
```

if i try to inject this script it doesnt work...

```
" onerror="alert(0)
```

This is probably because the website encodes double quote as `&quot`. I even tried double encoding by encoding double quote as `%2522`, but the webisite seems to render this as `"%22 onerror%22alert(0)"` and for some reason, the `%22` is not further decoded

Is there a way to bypass this?

Comment: did you try using single quotes?

Comment: yeah, doesnt work